# Ho to use xml or html layout with the Grails Log4j DSL

Tags: grails, groovy, log4j, pattern-layout

I am traying to get log4j to log to file in XMLLayout using the groovy log4j dsl. However, it seems that the "layout:"-part is being ignored. This is my setup:

```
appenders {
    file name: 'fileAppender', layout: xml, file: '/tmp/logs/applog.xml', threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO
    console name: "stdout", threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO
}

root {
    debug 'stdout', 'fileAppender'
}
```

So to stdout I corectly get my info-level pattern layout, but in the file I also get pattern-layout...

What's the trick here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. I've fixed it for 2.0.1: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8635

The workaround as you found is to use the constructor explicitly instead of the DSL shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found out that you can just use
  layout: new XMLLayout()
or
  layout: new HTMLLayout()

But still, in the documentation it says

> By default the Log4j DSL assumes that you want to use a PatternLayout.
>   However, there are other layouts available including:
>
> ```
> xml - Create an XML log file
> html - Creates an HTML log file
> simple - A simple textual log
> pattern - A Pattern layout
> ```

It seems to me that the shortcuts for xml and html don't work.